# using events in out of order execution in opencl

Tags: c++, opencl

Using events in out of order execution in opencl

I am new to opencl programming paradigm, so bear with me if I am doing something bad. 
I tried to create a std::vector and use it in the enququemigratemem and enquuekernel, but it either fails with an invalid event or the CPU emulation is failing.

```
// defined the events variables as global variables

cl::Event new_event;
std::vector<cl::Event> write_event(3);
std::vector<cl::Event> read_event(3);


 // in a allocator function I am pushing the new event in here

A()
{

     for (int i = 0  ; i < 2 ; i++){
        (write_event).push_back(new_event);
        (read_event).push_back(new_event);
     }

 }  

 // top function calling the kernel function.

  top()
  {

   for(i=0;i,50;i++)
    {

       func1()

     }

   }
  // actual exectuion  

   func1()
   {


    cl_int err;

    int falgs = k%2+1;


    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
      S[i] = i[i];
     }

       OCL_CHECK(err, buffer_source[falgs] = cl::Buffer(context, 
        CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
              sizeof(uint16_t) * PatternLength, S, &err));

       OCL_CHECK(err, buffer_output[falgs] = 
       cl::Buffer(context,CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
              sizeof(uint32_t), result, &err));

      uint16_t set =0;


       OCL_CHECK(err, err = 
       q.enqueueMigrateMemObjects({buffer_source[falgs]},
       0,NULL,&write_event[falgs]));


     OCL_CHECK(err, err = krnl_cluster.setArg(0, buffer_source[falgs]));

     OCL_CHECK(err, err = krnl_cluster.setArg(5, buffer_output[falgs]));

     OCL_CHECK(err, err = krnl_cluster.setArg(6, PatternLength));

     OCL_CHECK(err, err = krnl_cluster.setArg(7, MaxTrialsForPV));

     OCL_CHECK(err, err = krnl_cluster.setArg(8, set));

        std::cout<<" 3 "<<std::endl;

     OCL_CHECK(err, err = q.enqueueTask(krnl_cluster, &write_event ));

     //, &kernel_events[falgs]));

    std::cout<<"after the enqueue teask"<<std::endl;

    q.finish();

       OCL_CHECK(err, err = 
      q.enqueueMigrateMemObjects({buffer_output[falgs]},             
      CL_MIGRATE_MEM_OBJECT_HOST));

      //,&eventList,&read_event[falgs][0]));


    }
```

I am trying to do out of order execution, I have the below questions:

1. do I have to create a new event for every kernel execution or can I use the existing events
2. do I have to create 50 buffers or can I create 2 buffers and reuse them, how to do that?
3. what am I doing wrong in my program.
4. should I always set all the kernel arguments using set kernel args ?
5. For reducing application time, should I allocate my buffers in my class constructor or create it while I am calling the kernel multiple times ?
6. what are the most time consumed opencl API which I can replace them?
7. I researched on some of the examples on opencl, and I found that they don't release the buffers/events in C++ opencl code, while they do in C openCL. Does C++ openCL API automatically does that

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You're using the same event for everything, which will not work. I recommend getting your code to work with no events, on an in-order queue before trying to add events.

Comment: Ho ohlr, Yes it works with in-order-queue. I unable to wrap around the idea of using multiple events, can you give a simple example.

Comment: Events are used to build a dependency graph. Each clEnqueue API can return an event; store it and either wait on it or pass it to one or more downstream enqueue as something to wait on. Do not reuse event.

Comment: 1) like Dithermaster said, do not use the same event for two different commands. 2) you can reuse cl::Buffer class instances, but keep in mind their contents will be overwritten 3) hard to say with most code missing 4) only the arguments that changed since last clEnqueueNDR on that kernel 5) minimize calls to all clCreate APIs, ideally create buffers & queues just once and reuse them 6) what i said for 5 + you should take care to only use clFinish() when it's really needed, otherwise use clFlush() 7) yes the C++ wrapper takes care of releasing underlying CL objects

Comment: Also about events: it's your responsibility to release them. IOW, when you do this: q.enqueueTask(krnl_cluster, &write_event) - then write_event is created with reference count 2 - one reference for the API (while it's executing the command) and one reference for YOU. So you must release it (in C++, either delete the cl::Event object or let it go out of scope). I'd suggest you drop the std::vector of events and instead simply create them as stack variables inside the loop; that way they'll be released at the end of every loop iteration.